# Please help! Delegate returns null via Dipendency Injection

Tags: mocking

Can someone please help?

I use Google code’s Moq framework for mocking within my Unit Tests and Unity for Dependency Injection.

In my Test class

```
private Mock<ICustomerSearchService> CustomerSearchServiceMock = null;
private CustomerService customerService = null;

private void SetupMainData()
{
    CustomerSearchServiceMock = new Mock<ICustomerSearchService>();
    customerService = new CustomerService ();

    // CustomerSearchService is a property in CustomerService and dependency is  configuered via Unity
    customerService.CustomerSearchService = CustomerSearchServiceMock.Object;

     Customer c = new Customer ()
     {
         ID = "AT"
     };

     CustomerSearchServiceMock.Setup(s => s.GetCustomer(EqualsCondition)).Returns(c); 
}


[TestMethod]
public void GetCustomerData_Test_Method()
{
    SetupMainData()
    var customer = customerService.GetCustomerData("AT");
}


 public static bool EqualsCondition(Customer customer)
 {
     return customer.ID.Equals("AT");
 }
```

---

CustomerService class

```
public class CustomerService : ICustomerService
{

    [Dependency]
    public ICustomerSearchService CustomerSearchService { get; set; }


    public IEnumerable<SomeObject> GetCustomerData(string custID)
    {

      I GET Null for customer ?????}
      var customer = CustomerSearchService.GetCustomer (c => c.ID.Equals(custID));

       //Do more things
    }
}
```

When I debug the code I can see CustomerSearchService has a proxy object, but the customer returns as null. Any ideas? Or is there something missing here?

---

Note: ICustomerSearchService I have implemented below method.

```
     Customer GetCustomer(Func<Customer, bool> predicate);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this problem in Rhino.Mocks too (mocking, lambdas and stubbing/expectations).  See:

http://groups.google.com/group/rhinomocks/msg/318a35ae7536d90a